# When continuous export job run time overlaps with intervalBetweenRuns in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have created a continuous export job with 5m as `intervalBetweenRuns`. What will happen if the export itself takes more than 5mins? Is there any real problem here other than export getting slightly delayed? Lets say export goes on for 10 mins, will it still try to take care of the export run that it missed or it will keep waiting for the next window before running? The following diagram illustrates my question:-

[image]

Now consider a scenario -- the interval is set to 5 mins and a single run of the export job takes 10-15 mins to run. It's all right if the export continuously keeps running back to back but is there any real issue other than just data delay? Data delay (data arriving in the destination) is fine with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If some runs take longer than the interval between runs, that's fine. The continuous export will catch up. If this constantly happens, then the continuous export will start developing a lag, and will never be able to catch up, of course. In any case, no data is ever skipped.

Comment: thanks, if I suddenly alter intervalBetweenRuns from 5m to 1h for an existing continuous export job -- will it run immediately (I assume any continuous export job starts as soon as we create or alter it ) and then after that 1 hour from the value shown in 'LastRunTime' as shown by .show command after the current run suceeds?

Comment: it's not guaranteed to run immediately. The alter command doesn't trigger the execution. There's an offline process that checks for pending continuous exports to run, and compares the last run with the interval between runs. So most probably it'll run an hour after previous execution.

Comment: so I guess the only way to guarantee that hourly job execution window starts at a specific time is to delete the existing export job and create at desired time window.

Comment: it might help if you provide more details on the scenario and what you're trying to achieve. If your intention is to run an hourly export job at exactly every hour (potentially summarizing data for the past hour?), then continuous-export is not your best choice, as there are no guarantees on the exact time it runs. I would suggest using "regular" export commands and orchestrating them to run every hour. If I misunderstood the scenario, please provide more details and I'll try to help further.

Comment: I think yes it makes more sense to have a normal export and orchestrate it hourly. Yes my use case is just that to have it exported hourly at fixed intervals. thx.